# PHP function * gets replaced with Ã— so getting error

Tags: php, function, replace

Hey i am a noob when it comes to php because i have just started, and I am trying to execute a ffmpeg code through a function but when i try to execute it, i get an error because '480×360' is replaced with '480Ã—360'and i am not sure whats wrong.
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `×`and not an `x`. The latter is an ascii value, the other some unicode character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x` character, rather than being a lowercase letter x, is the unicode [codepoint D7](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) which is the *multiplication sign*.  This has the UTF-8 representation C397.  You are seeing the bytes C3 and 97 which are appearing as your accented A and dash due to you viewing things in the Windows CP1252 encoding.

As regards a specific resolution, you could try replacing the multiplication sign with a lower case x.  You've not mentioned your specific function, so this may not be the appropriate resolution.

Comment: Other solutions are to use a HTML entity for the character, or change the page encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: thanks i replaced it with the normal x and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

You are passing the weird version of the x and not an actual `x`. You need to change it to simply be an `x`.

Comment: mmm gotta love down votes without explanations :) Still going to be stubborn as I see it as answering the question, perhaps without the excellent explanation that borrible gave, but does that warrant downvotes? /me shrugs